# bluetoothd daemon spamd journal and slow boot due to bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth, startup, 20.10

On groovy I have a lot entries from bluetoothd daemon in journal debug mode shows  [paste][1].

/etc/bluetooth/main.conf file is untouched, no own changes made by me.

The real problem is startup time is a little bit slowed, because related to bluetooth.

```
systemd-analyze critical-chain 
The time when unit became active or started is printed after the "@" character.
The time the unit took to start is printed after the "+" character.

graphical.target @27.215s
└─multi-user.target @27.214s
  └─blueman-mechanism.service @9.601s +17.612s
    └─basic.target @9.545s
      └─sockets.target @9.544s
        └─uuidd.socket @9.543s
          └─sysinit.target @9.306s
            └─haveged.service @9.304s
              └─apparmor.service @7.940s +1.345s
                └─local-fs.target @7.936s
                  └─run-user-1000.mount @26.184s
                    └─local-fs-pre.target @3.738s
                      └─systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service @3.624s +110ms
                        └─systemd-sysusers.service @3.035s +586ms
                          └─systemd-remount-fs.service @2.768s +149ms
                            └─systemd-journald.socket @2.615s
                              └─-.mount @2.224s
                                └─system.slice @2.224s
                                  └─-.slice @2.224s
```

current running Kernel

```
uname -a
Linux beelzemon 5.8.0-29-generic #31-Ubuntu SMP Fri Nov 6 12:37:59 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

at last hardeware  and module info

```
lsusb | grep -i blue
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0a5c:21e6 Broadcom Corp. BCM20702 Bluetooth 4.0 [ThinkPad]
```

and

```
systool -m  btusb -v
Module = "btusb"

  Attributes:
    coresize            = "57344"
    initsize            = "0"
    initstate           = "live"
    refcnt              = "0"
    srcversion          = "833AC4BC1801D5ADA5F03CE"
    taint               = ""
    uevent              = <store method only>
    version             = "0.8"

  Parameters:
    disable_scofix      = "N"
    enable_autosuspend  = "Y"
    force_scofix        = "N"
    reset               = "Y"

  Sections:
```

Thanks for reading.
[1]: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/cXwRVXjgM7/

Comment: What version of Ubuntu and server or desktop?

Comment: Ubuntu 20.10 with gnome3.

Comment: `sudo apt purge blueman ` solved it. The blueman-applet was crashing.